# What to do when the question is updated to make your answer obsolete

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I looked over the "your question may already be answered" suggestions box and didn't see anything that fit, but I've been known to miss those before so apologies in advance if this has been asked before (I imagined it must have been, but see nothing).

What is the correct action when something like this happens:

> - A question is posted to SO.
> - You see a few missing lines of code that are the problem, so you post an answer saying so.
> - OP takes the code you've suggested and copies it into their question, along with something like "EDIT: I added this new code and it fixed part of the problem but it still doesn't work."

At this point the answer doesn't fit the question anymore; on the surface the answerer looks pretty stupid for saying "add these lines" when the lines were already in the question (as far as new viewers can tell, anyway). I commented to the OP and asked a follow-up question to see if I could figure out the rest of the problem, but no dice on that just yet and in the meantime the answer is sitting there looking silly.

So, what's the proper procedure in this case? Delete the answer? Rollback the question edit? Leave it sitting there as is until we get to the bottom of the problem? (What if it turns into one of those rabbit-hole questions where the problem keeps changing with every fix?) Just leave it alone and forget about it?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I've read that post before, and used it in other situations. However in this case I'm not sure what to do because *the question was edited and my answer no longer seems sensical*. It hasn't turned into a rabbit-hole/chameleon question just yet. But I'm unsure what to do with my answer/the question considering the edit.

Comment: @WendiKidd can you link to the post?  Depending on how radical the edit, it might need to be rolled back if it completely invalidated your answer

Comment: You have (I think) enough rep on SO Wendi; roll back the question so that your answer makes sense and leave a comment for the OP asking them to ask another question if they have one. Alternatively, if you're feeling generous update your answer... from what you've said, be feeling nice if you decide to change it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Thanks for the advice. I've rolled back as you said. I'm still trying to sort out exactly what the problem still is; if I can figure it out I will definitely update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @psubsee2003 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283446/accessing-object-from-array-within-an-array-defined-in-model-class). I've rolled back as you both suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rollback the edit such that the question contains only that code for which you answered. Also, leave a comment stating the reason for the rollback.

Beyond that, the question is still not a chameleon question. So, you should ideally, continue to help the OP to solve their problem. However, this is, of course, not necessary.